# Declaration of functions inside a module OCaml

Tags: function, ocaml

So, i'am learning OCaml step by step and i've recently met the great world of "module langage" in OCaml.

Here is my problem:

```
module type TEST = sig
    val addend : 'a -> list
end

module Test : TEST =
    struct
        let addend (val,lol) = 
        val::lol
    end
```

when i try to use this inside the interpretor it tells me that i have a `syntax error` ...
I know that's this kind of anoying question asked by this guy who's a noob and thinks stack overflow is here to rewrite is poorly optimised code but still, after hours spend searching for a solution i've almost gived up at this point...

OCaml is cool, but why is it so hard.

Comment: I think that statically typed languages like OCaml are more difficult, at first, than dynamically typed languages such as Clojure, but static typing has benefits.  If you think about how many type annotations have to specified exactly correctly in Java, OCaml looks very easy by comparison.  Perhaps OCaml's module language is the hardest part, but you can do a lot without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the definition of the type of your module : you have to specify the type of element of your list. You cannot use `list` alone.

The following code will compile :

```
module type TEST = sig
    val addend : 'a -> 'a list
end;;
```

But will not do what you want as you want to define later a function that takes a element, a list and puts this element in this list.
So the signature of such function is :

```
'a -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

So the type of your module shall be :

```
module type TEST = sig
    val addend : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list
end;;
```

And the implementation :

```
module Test : TEST =
struct 
     let addend a l = a::l
end
;;
```

Please note that in your code, you may be influenced by C like language where you pass the arguments in parenthesis. In Ocaml, parenthesis are used for tuples ; this means that your implementation was different from the signature.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it seems like i need to be way more focused when writing my code... Also thanks for the signature, i did not know you need to define your list as an undefined list type...

Comment: Pierre G didn't mention it, but I think that another problem with your code, xoxel, is that you can't use `val` as a variable name because it's a special keyword.  (I am a beginner myself, but I believe this is correct.)

Answer (score 1):

You get a syntax error becaue `val` is a keyword. You cannot use it as an identifier.